# What is the trick to learn x86 assembly language on Windows PC?

Tags: assembly, x86

After years of effort, I am unable to learn x86 assembly language by self studying.

Every assembly language book I found, starts with some discussions on number systems, then, registers, debug, then so on. After reading one or two chapters my brain becomes messed up with tons of information and lots of questions. I skim through the book back and forth for finding the answers of my questions. Then all information, I read from the book, seems useless. This happens over and over again.

I must be missing something.

What is the basic technique to learn assembly language?

What steps do I need to follow?

Comment: "Then I stop reading [and tinkering]" - sorry, nobody else can help you with this. Maybe it's just not an interesting enough pursuit. Or maybe there is not enough compensation. If that is the case, do something else. *I* would have to be reimbursed a lot to mess with assembly as it doesn't interest me. Anyway, Off Topic.

Comment: I find reading programming books less useful compared to actual practice. If you've been actually practicing, welp, I don't know

Comment: There is no trick. Just try harder. It wasn't easy for me either.

Comment: Baby steps : start with hello world, then capture one keystroke, later, capture a string . . . I recommend you EMU8086 : small, free, easy to use. That's how I started.

Comment: I learned asm mostly by looking at disassembly of compiler output (of code for functions I understood the source for).  Also, understanding the concept of the architectural state of the machine (value of every register), and how every insn creates a new state from the old state.  I have to disagree with writing whole simple programs in asm.  Knowing what a calling convention is, and recognizing `push` / `call` sequences is important, but asm these days is most useful for optimizing single functions, or even just inner loops.  You need some idea of how that fits in to compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) x86 probably the worst instruction set to learn first.  just because you have one is not a good reason (you may not know it but for every x86 you have several arm processors not that using those is a good idea either).

2) start with a simulator, bare metal makes it a lot easier...pcemu for example.  ideally something that shows you stuff as it runs, register and memory accesses, not gdb type of a thing as that wont prevent you from a hang or crash or necessarily help for those.

3) arm/thumb or msp430 are good instruction sets

Nevertheless, this is on linux but can be done simply with windows as well..

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b );

int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun(1,2));
    return(0);
}
```

fun.c

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a+b+7);
}
```

build and run

```
gcc -O2 -c fun.c -o fun.o
gcc -O2 main.c fun.o -o main
./main
10
```

now...

```
objdump -D fun.o
... the part we care about:
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   8d 44 37 07             lea    0x7(%rdi,%rsi,1),%eax
   4:   c3  
...
```

from that make fun.s

```
.globl fun
fun:
    lea    0x8(%rdi,%rsi,1),%eax
    retq
```

changing the 7 to an 8

```
as fun.s -o funs.o
gcc -O2 main.c funs.o -o main
./main
11
```

there you go, an program with some x86 assembly, worry about main later. running on an operating system what you can do is extremely limited, so your hands will be tied, often leading to general protection faults crashing the program.

You can make increasingly more complicated C programs, compile and disassemble, look those instructions up on the web or in the books you have.  Make mods where possible and see what happens.

Compilers do not necessarily generate code that is easy to follow, but it is code that obviously works.  and the code generated is not the only way, also play with different optimization levels, for this kind of thing more optimization is better so long as you can write high level code that doesnt have dead code in it that gets optimized out.